# Java (JGIT) Files.delete() fails to delete a file, but file.delete() succeeds

Tags: java, filesystems, jgit

I'm cloning a git repo into a temp directory using jgit (version `4.8.0.201706111038-r`) and adding a shutdown hook to delete the temp directory after termination. However, the shutdown hook fails to delete some files from within the `.git` subdirectory (despite closing the Git object, as required by jgit).

The funny thing though, is that the deletion fails only if I use the Path API (`Files.delete(<PATH>)`), but not if I delete using the old `file.delete()`.

Here's a minimal standalone example whose only dependency is jgit 4.8.0.201706111038-r:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    String gitRepo = "https://github.com/netgloo/spring-boot-samples.git";
    Path localDir = Files.createTempDirectory(null);

    // Clone repo
    Git git = Git.cloneRepository().setURI(gitRepo).setBranch("master").setDirectory(localDir.toFile()).call();

    // Print some stuff to make sure that the git repo actually works
    for (RevCommit c : git.log().call()) {
        System.out.println(c);
    }

    git.getRepository().close(); // Close all the things!
    git.close(); // Close all the things!

    // Delete
    Files.walkFileTree(localDir, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        void safeDelete(Path p) {
            try {
                Files.delete(p);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                try {
                    Files.delete(p);
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                    System.err.println("Failed to delete " + p + " due to " + e.getClass().getSimpleName() + " using Files.detlete().\nTrying toFile().delete(): " + p.toFile().delete());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            safeDelete(file);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException e) throws IOException {
            safeDelete(dir);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
}
```

Output:

```
...
Failed to delete C:\Users\malt\AppData\Local\Temp\7908805853015958247\.git\objects\pack\pack-9cc3ec0769e34546bb7683f4e22ef67b3c800444.idx due to AccessDeniedException using Files.detlete().
Trying toFile().delete(): true
Failed to delete C:\Users\malt\AppData\Local\Temp\7908805853015958247\.git\objects\pack\pack-9cc3ec0769e34546bb7683f4e22ef67b3c800444.pack due to AccessDeniedException using Files.detlete().
Trying toFile().delete(): true
```

Can anyone explain why this happens? And is there a way to get JGIT to properly close these files so that `Files.delete()` works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When obtained from a `CloneCommand`, `Git::close` alone should be enough to release all file handles, held by JGit for a given repository. It simply delegates to `Repository::close` in this case.

I think the difference between `Files::delete()` and `File::delete()` that you are seeing is explained here:

[Difference between Files#delete(Path) and File#delete()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139482/difference-between-filesdeletepath-and-filedelete)

Probably unrelated, but I think nonetheless worth mentioning, is an issue with the recently introduced background thread for auto-gc. It may also prevent a repository from being deleted successfully. See this mailing list thread:

https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jgit-dev/msg03370.html

To work around the latter issue, I disabled auto-gc in the configuration of the repository like this:

```java
StoredConfig config = repository.getConfig();
config.setBoolean(CONFIG_GC_SECTION, null, CONFIG_KEY_AUTODETACH, false);
config.setInt(CONFIG_GC_SECTION, null, CONFIG_KEY_AUTOPACKLIMIT, -1);
config.setInt(CONFIG_GC_SECTION, null, CONFIG_KEY_AUTO, -1);
config.save();
```

The constants are imported static from `ConfigConstants`.

Does that match your problem?

Comment: I realize that the double `close()` call is redundant, I just wanted to make the call very explicit for the purpose of the question. Regarding the GC configuration - I've added the code you've provided to the reproduction code, but I get the same behavior. The Files.delete() vs File.delete() explanation seems to be on point though.

Comment: I also saw no effect after disabling auto-gc with your snippet, but I thought you may run into this once, the Files::close vs File::close issue is solved.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann This does not solves the issue I am affraid. I have seen 2 or 3 cases about locked files after closing repository on some mailing lists but found no resolution to this.

Comment: If you see these problems with the latest version of JGit and can reproduce it, you may want to file a bug.

Answer (score 1):

If somebody still faces the same issue, what worked for me is to force calling gc to release the files locking

```
gitReference.gc().call()
```

Here is the full close method of mine:

```
public void close() {
    if (gitReference != null) {
       try {            
            gitReference.close();           
            gitReference.gc().call();
        } catch (GitAPIException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        gitReference = null;
    }
}
```

Good Luck

Jalal