# How to choose between Files.delete and File.delete

Tags: java, delete-file

In windows there is a [known bug](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/326549/you-cannot-view-or-change-the-read-only-or-the-system-attributes-of-fo) where a folder can have read only property enable.

I have a file that have this property enabled and I need to delete it. But File.delete delete this folder whereas Files.delete can't.

Here a sample to reproduce my issue. I am in the case where the folder i want to delete is empty

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File tmpDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
        File someDir = new File(tmpDir, "someDir");

        Files.setAttribute(someDir.toPath(), "dos:readonly", true);

        //        someDir.delete(); //ok
        Files.delete(someDir.toPath()); //fail

}
```

Files.delete seems more appropriated according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139482/difference-between-filesdeletepath-and-filedelete) but in my case it doesn't work.

In this case I can set the property back to false and I am fine but what is the right choice to do between those two method ? Should I try to use both if one failed ?

Comment: Do you have files in this directory ?

Comment: No file in this directory (good point, I update the question) . The code posted here is sufficient to reproduce the problem

Comment: Ok ! So it seems that `Files.delete()` respects the readonly property despite the Window bug while `File.delete()` preserves the Windows bug.  Conceptually it it wrong that a read only directory may be deleted. So I would try to change the file property. Don't you have the permission at runtime to disable the readonly property on this dir such as :         `Files.setAttribute(someDir.toPath(), "dos:readonly", false);` ?

Comment: Yes in my case no problem to set the property back to false (may be i am moving the problem to set attribut now). But what if I found the opposite scenario ? What's the best way to deal with this problem ? Should I use Files.delete with the property to false or simply use File.delete and no worries.....

Comment: Personally, I don't like any of these ways  : old and flawed API that respects the Windows behavior  and a recent and better designed API but that is not conform to the underlying OS. But to get a relevant error message if the operation fails I think that I would stick to `Files.delete()`. Now in cases of the file attribute cannot be changed in "not readonly", using `File.delete()` as workaround is probably the way.